# C++ : Parent calling a function from child that has not been declared in itself. How?

Tags: c++, parent-child, pure-virtual

The following code compiles and runs correctly and it has been taken from a [website](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method/cpp/2) about c++ design patterns. What i fail to understand is how does this even compiles. The issues are

1) As the title says, the parent calls a function named CreateDocument which doesnt exist in its declaration in NewDocument(char *name) function . A function with the same name but different parameters is declared as a pure virtual.

2)I also fail to see how the method "NewDocument(char *name)" works, since it has no return type. It is not a constructor of the base class.

The code snippet is in the following. The full code can be found at the link provided above.

```
    class Application
    {
      public:
        Application(): _index(0)
        {
            cout << "Application: ctor" << endl;
        }
        /* The client will call this "entry point" of the framework */
        NewDocument(char *name)
        {
            cout << "Application: NewDocument()" << endl;
            /* Framework calls the "hole" reserved for client customization              */
            _docs[_index] = CreateDocument(name);
            _docs[_index++]->Open();
        }
        void OpenDocument(){}
        void ReportDocs();
        /* Framework declares a "hole" for the client to customize */
        virtual Document *CreateDocument(char*) = 0;
      private:
        int _index;
        /* Framework uses Document's base class */
        Document *_docs[10];
    };

    void Application::ReportDocs()
    {
      cout << "Application: ReportDocs()" << endl;
      for (int i = 0; i < _index; i++)
        cout << "   " << _docs[i]->GetName() << endl;
    }


    /* Customization of framework defined by client */
    class MyApplication: public Application
    {
      public:
        MyApplication()
        {
            cout << "MyApplication: ctor" << endl;
        }
        /* Client defines Framework's "hole" */
        Document *CreateDocument(char *fn)
        {
            cout << "   MyApplication: CreateDocument()" << endl;
            return new MyDocument(fn);
        }
    };
```

Comment: questions posted to stack overflow must be self contained and not rely on information off site.  This is so the answer remains useful even if external website information changes.  In this case, it appears that maybe the website you're getting code from just isn't very thorough and has posted bad code.

Comment: I am not questioning or starting a debate about the information in another site. I am simply asking how this code compiles since to my knowledge it doesnt seem even possible. I have looked  for the syntax that makes this possible for quite some time and couldnt find any answers. The snippet i have posted is enough to shed light on the matter even if the external site does close.

Comment: The code on the linked page doesn't compile because it tries to include a non-existent header and is missing other needed ones, plus namespace issues, and the missing return type for that NewDocument method.... I would forget you ever saw that page.

Comment: What compiler are you using that actually accepts that program?

Comment: I have actually corrected those obvious mistakes, i am well aware that the iosteam.h is pretty much deprecated. Aside from those obvious mistakes i still do not understand how does this compile.

Comment: It *doesn't* compile with any C++ compiler I'm aware of or tried. Which one are you using?

Comment: I am using Mingw on Codeblocks

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe that. MinGW is a gcc port, and I just tried a half dozen gcc versions going back to 4.1. And clang, msvc, and icc. After fixing the header issues, none accept that method not having a return type.

Comment: Looking at the link (only because I recognize the site) I see `#include <iostream.h>`. That hasn't been valid for a long, long time. I think someone is foisting TurboC++ code off on you, and TuboC++ is bronze-freaking-age C++. The rules have changed [big-time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBAl9cchQac) since the early 1990's.

Answer (score 0):

1)  `NewDocument` calls the pure virtual method `CreateDocument`. This method**is** declared taking a `char*` and returns a `Document*`.  `MyApplication` also declares and implements `CreateDocument` that takes a `char*` and returns a `Document*`.  In other words, they have the same signature.  The actual names of the parameters are not involved in this resolution and, for this purpose, ignored.

2)  The method `Application::NewDocument(char *name)` is just used in too old a fashion, predating the first C++ standard.  It should be declared `void NewDocument(char *name)` to work.

As mentioned on the comments there are a whole lot of other issues with th e code, like there is a missing destructor `~Application()` missing that is needed to remove the memory leak.  `~Application() { while (_index-- > 0) delete _docs[_index]; }`